# filter the typed first letters related only

Tags: sql-server

```
List<string> Cat= new List<string>();
string maincon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(maincon);
string sqlQuery = string.Format("select Keyword from RR_PRIAM where Keyword **LIKE '%{0}%'"**, sub_cat);

con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con);

SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (sdr.Read())
{
    Cat.Add(sdr.GetString(0));
}

con.Close();
return Cat;
```

Like expression how will change please guide me

```
string sqlQuery = string.Format("select Keyword from RR_PRIAM where Keyword **LIKE '%{0}%'", sub_cat);
```

Please someone help me - I want to change the search first letter like p means

```
print
post
prince
```

Comment: Careful, yout code is open to injection attacks. You really need to use parameterisation.

Comment: Filter: LIKE 'Char%'

Answer (score 0):

To search for rows where `Keyword` starts with `sub_cat` instead of contains `sub_cat`, you need to drop the leading wildcard `%`. More importantly, as Larmu pointed out, you need to parameterize your query.

Something like:

```
...
string sqlQuery = "select Keyword from RR_PRIAM where Keyword LIKE @prefix + '%'";
...
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con);
command.Parameters.Add("@prefix ", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1).Value = sub_cat;
...
```